# show frontend page only user is logged in in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to **show** the customers details and bought products in frontend page

how can i show the my **custom module's page** only **if** the user is **logged** **in**.

Comment: Is your frontend page is CMS page or your custom module's page?

Comment: its my custom module's page bro

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `if condition` in the controller of your custom page.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) 
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function execute(){
    $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
    if($customer->isLoggedIn){
        /*
        ...
        your controller's code
        ...
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to render the content via ajax, else if FPC is enabled, content may either be of logged-in or logged-out case.